# Reverting from an automatic property to regular property in C#4.0

Tags: c#-4.0

Can anyone explain me how to revert from automatic implemented poperty (AIP)A to regular property.

For eg. iF i have declared a AIP, then how to make it regular (how to write some code in get and set accessor method.)

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

AIP can be used only "[when no additional logic is required in the property accessors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)" so, to revert them, just declare them the "old way": define a private property (if needed) and put the needed code in your property accessors blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to get your job done
public String YourProperty
    { 
    get 
    {
    //append your business logic for the property here return something after some calculation
    //e.g. area of a geometric figure
    } 
    set 
    {
    // Append your logic her fir e.g concatenation of firstname and lastname 
    //(Firstname + Lastname);
    }
    }